# Zoho Mail API authtoken issue

Tags: javascript, angular, http, https, zoho

I am trying to get/send mails using Zoho Mail API V2, there are few steps like getting code then getting authtoken then making request for getting all mails etc.

Domain configuration: bgbs-dev.firebaseapp.com
Redirect URL : https://bgbs-dev.firebaseapp.com/zoho

1. Get Code(GET Request) : https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=VirtualOffice.messages.READ&client_id=1000.96035O2MGZKOPSBYMU&response_type=code&access_type=online&redirect_uri=https://bgbs-dev.firebaseapp.com/zoho&state=123456
2. Making Post Request for authtoken :

   authToken(code: string): Observable {

   ```
   let params = new HttpParams();
   params = params.append('code', code); // getting code from above request
   params = params.append('grant_type', "authorization_code");
   params = params.append('scope', "messages.READ");
   params = params.append('clientId', "1000.3BU2GUYF4SBYMU"); 
   params = params.append('client_secret', "9853c68cf3ab913e13afd8a05"); 
   params = params.append('redirect_uri', "https://bgbs-dev.firebaseapp.com/zoho"); 
   params = params.append('state', "123456"); 
   return this.http.post<any>('http://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token', {params: params});

     }
   ```

I am able to get toke if making request from postman, but there is CORS origin error/Invalid URL while requesting from angular app.

Your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: it seems you are missing the url in your post why is it empty?

Comment: I am adding URL

Comment: Hi have you already added this on the header?
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *